# Error with code Python Beautifulsoup extract specific link with text

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup

Hello i have a problem with my code, i tried to search one specific url with this code but it doesn't show up anything

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

html_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://www.fiuxy.net/misc.php")}):
    print link.get('href')
```

[image]

i only want the link that it has the "10" text , it changes everytime, (is not the same everytime)

What i have done bad?

Sorry if my english is bad bcause im spanish :(

Comment: `soup.select('.dar-puntos > a')[-1].text`

Comment: where i add that? @AvinashRaj

Comment: replace for loop with the above and don't forget to add print before that.

Comment: `for link in soup.select('.dar-puntos > a')[-1].text:
        print link` like this?

Comment: no, `print soup.select('.dar-puntos > a')[-1].text`

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable :(

Comment: post the actual html text..

Comment: the python code or the html code of the image

Comment: html code of the image..

Comment: if you want only the link that has "10" text, you can put a if condition where the encode_contents() == "10"

Comment: here is the code http://pastebin.com/FbK2nuqq

Comment: @MiquelTorres it works for me.. see http://pastebin.com/7dyKiugh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone but i solved it myself with selenium,

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver.get(url)
puntos = driver.find_element_by_link_text(u"10")
print (puntos.get_attribute('href'))
```